# use progressbar do display text limit of a memo

Tags: delphi

My cxmemo is limited to 150 characters (maxlenght).
I would like to use the cxProgressBar to visually represent this limitation.
How can I do this ?
I tried :

```
procedure TMain_Form.cxMemo1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not  (trim(cxmemo1.lines.Text) = '')  then begin
cxProgressBar1.Position := cxProgressBar1.Position +cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxmemo1.Text);
end;
end;
```

But it does not work...
I want the progressbar to rise when user is typing and shrink if he is deleting characters in the memo.
How can I make this work ?

Comment: Set `progressbar.max` to maxlength and update the position with `Length(cxmemo1.Text);`

Comment: why is it that the progressbar never goes back to 0% ? Even when memo is empty it stays at 1%. - very nice answer thank you.

Comment: What is the min value of the progressbar? And do you still have the check to not update the progressbar when the memo is empty?

Comment: Min = 0 No I did not do the check ...

Comment: Please feel free to post your own answer, it is encouraged on SO. In two days or so, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TMain_Form.cxMemo1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Trim(cxMemo1.Lines.Text) <> '' then begin
    cxProgressBar1.Visible := True;
    cxProgressBar1.Position := Length(cxMemo1.Text);
    if Length(cxMemo1.Text) = cxMemo1.Properties.MaxLength then
      ShowMessage('You exceeded the maximum number of characters !' + #13#10 +'Limit is : 150 '+ #13#10 +'For more, use the field "memo" .');
  end else begin
    if cxMemo1.Lines.Text.IsEmpty then
      cxProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    cxProgressBar1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just as suggestion, try to improve the indentation! The code is hard to read

Comment: Every time `Text` is read, a new `string` is allocated. This code is allocating 4 strings where only 1 is needed. Cache the trimmed `Text` to a local variable and use that everywhere as needed.